# A clean interface for hooking into sectioning commands

Tags: sectioning, latex3, xparse, hooks

Is there an easy way to hook LaTeX's sectioning commands, short of the good ol' `\let` + `\def` (or, with `xparse`, `\let` + `\RenewDocumentCommand{s O{} m}`)? I'm looking for something in the spirit of `everypage`, `everyshi` and the like.

The `titlesec` package offers a hook but the section name does not seem to be available there. I want to perform custom actions for every section, i.e. for each instance of `\chapter{...}`, `\section{...}`, `\subsection{...}` etc..

Currently I have a `\let` + `\RenewDocumment` command to insert an invisible `fixme` note after each section.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[inline,draft,nomargin]{fixme}
\fxusetheme{color}

\makeatletter
\let\kmue@section=\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{ s O{} m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \kmue@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \kmue@section{#3}%
    \fxnote[noinline]{{\color{black}#3}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \listoffixmes
  \section{A}
  \fxwarning{First warning}
  \section{B}
  \fxerror{Second error}
\end{document}
```

(I'm aware that the code is broken as it doesn't respect the second argument.)

[image: Result of compilation]

### Question

Is there something more like

```
\everychapter[starred=false]{\fxnote{...}}
```

instead of a home-grown redefinition? The `\fxnote` command should be able to access the section title.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to hook into/or do...

Comment: Please be (a lot...) more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the problem with redefining it? There is no `\everychapter...` as far as I know.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: MWE added.

Comment: What is contained within `\fxfatal`'s argument? Something pertaining to the sectional argument?

Comment: Except you MWE does not compile, because it it missing some packages.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: My fault, fixed.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, the `\fxnote` (was `\fxfatal`) should be able to access the section title.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the issue is.  How about `\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[inline,draft,nomargin]{fixme}
\fxusetheme{color}
\makeatletter
\let\kmue@section=\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{ s O{} m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \kmue@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \kmue@section{#3}%
    \def\tmp{#3}%
    \fxnote[noinline]{{\color{black}\tmp}}%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \listoffixmes
  \section{A}
  \fxwarning{First warning \tmp:}
  \section{B}
  \fxerror{Second error \tmp:}
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Isn't this pretty much my MWE? It works I just don't like the way I have to use `\RenewDocumentCommand`, and I'm looking for a more high-level abstraction.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Sorry, now I see the difference. No, my MWE works alright, no need to fix that. I'm just looking for a cleaner way to implement this.

Comment: Ok.  I just wasn't sure if there was a functional issue or if you just wanted a cleaner syntax.  Apparently, it is the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on the LaTeX definitions contained within `\section` to distinguish between the optional argument and/or whether you used a starred version. From my point of view, you should tap into `\@sect` (non-starred) or `\@ssect` (starred):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[inline,draft,nomargin]{fixme}
\fxusetheme{color}

\makeatletter

% Somewhat like \everysection[starred=false]{\fxnote{...}}
% \@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\fxnote[noinline]{{\color{black}#7}}%
   \@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

% Somewhat like \everysection[starred=true]{\fxnote{...}}
% \@ssect#1#2#3#4#5
\patchcmd{\@ssect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\fxnote[noinline]{{\color{black}#5}}%
   \@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes
\section{A}
\fxwarning{First warning}
\section*{B}
\fxerror{Second error}
\end{document}
```

Argument `#7` is the optional title for `\section`, while `#8` is the mandatory title. Argument `#5` for `\section*` points to the mandatory title.

However, this is no cleaner than redefining `\section` to suit your needs, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Will this work for all document classes, e.g., KOMA script or memoir?

Comment: @krlmlr: Most likely not; you'll have to find a package that redefines the way it works depending on the class. My next bet would be to look into [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) - part of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) - which captures the sectional unit name for referencing purposes.

Comment: The `nameref` code looks comprehensive and would be a solid basis for an `everysec` package (hint, hint) ;-) In the long run, many packages that now patch sectioning commands could use it.